# Why does output pipe through grep appear in chunks instead of line by line?

Tags: pipe, sh

I have a huge performence problem with a commandline. If I enter:

```
hcidump -a
```

I get following output:

```
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 42
    LE Advertising Report
      ADV_IND - Connectable undirected advertising (0)
      bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66 (Public)
      Flags: 0x06
      Unknown type 0xff with 25 bytes data
      RSSI: -26
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 41
    LE Advertising Report
      SCAN_RSP - Scan Response (4)
      bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66 (Public)
      Complete local name: 'BEACON 17:9F:66'
      TX power level: 0
      Unknown type 0x16 with 7 bytes data
      RSSI: -26
```

And every block of information comes in realtime on the screen. But as I only need the value out of RSSI I use this command to get it:

```
hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr' | grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'bdaddr 78:A5:04:17:9F:66' | grep -Po 'RSSI:\s+\K.*'
```

It works perfectly, but I have huge performence problems. As the two digit values are not come one by one on the screen, but in blocks. There happens nothing for 12-15seconds and then I get like 40 values at once. has any body an idea what the problem is?

Is the pipe-command using a buffer? 
Or has someone an idea how to shorten the command, showed above? to increase the performence?

Best regards Adrian

Comment: This is not a performance issue.

Answer (score 7):

The performance issue is caused by the `grep` commands detecting that their output is not to a terminal device so they use **block buffering** when printing their output. If you’re using GNU `grep`, you could use its `--line-buffered` which buffers by line instead of by *block* of data.

If you only want the RSSI value, you can replace the piped `grep` commands with one `sed` command:

```
hcidump -a | sed -n 's/[ \t]*RSSI: //p'
```

The `-n` option  tells `sed` to *not* print each line. It searches each line for the string `RSSI:` preceded by any number of whitespace characters and replaces the whole lot with an empty string. The final `p` instructs `sed` to print that line after the substitution has been carried out.

Since the `sed` command is printing directly to a terminal device, it should not block buffer its output. If you want it to print to something other than a terminal and you’re using GNU `sed`, you could use its `-u, --unbuffered` option to

> load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often

---

### General info on I/O Buffering

When a program prints text to an output stream, the printing is buffered.
There are two types:

- **Line buffering** means writing output whenever a newline is encountered.
- **Block buffering** means waiting for a certain amount of data before
  writing. The amount depends on the kernel configuration; 4096 bytes is the
  default for Linux.

### Standard streams

- `stdin` is always block buffered.
- `stderr` is line buffered.
- `stdout` depends on the output device:

  - Line buffering is used if it’s connected to a terminal device,
  - Block buffering is used if it’s not (e.g., `stdout` is connected to
    `stdin` of another program in a pipeline).

---

### Useful links

[Grep and Output
Buffering](http://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/grep-and-output-buffering/) provides
a decent introduction to the issue.

Pádraig Brady wrote an excellent article to explain what goes on at a kernel
level: [buffering in standard
streams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)

Jonathon Perkin explains how to fix this issue for many programs:
[How to fix stdio buffering](https://www.perkin.org.uk/posts/how-to-fix-stdio-buffering.html)

This Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question covers a number of solutions:
[Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/22812)